# Alter CONSTRAINT to only use stored_prodedure on insert (not on update)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, constraints

This is a new request since the old one couldn't be removed.

I want to alter a CONSTRAINT so it only uses a stored_procedure when I INSERT and NOT UPDATE a table

Is there a way to do this?

Kind regards.

Comment: A constraint? *uses* an SP? Sorry, but what does this mean? Either I have never heard of it, or *have* heard but under a different name. (Although I'm quite ready to find it something simple and well known, to my own shame.) Either way, please explain what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a INSTEAD OF Trigger to disable the CONSTRAINT then do the UPDATE. To disable the CONSTRAINT you can do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ConstraintName 

UPDATE...(FROM INSERTED)

ALTER TABLE YourTable CHECK CONSTRAINT ConstraintName
```

Comment: Ok this is what I am looking for, but how do I write the statement in the middle?
Update (from inserted)?
Lets say the "real" statement is update table_1 set name='pelle',age=32 where id=283 and name<>''

Comment: It seems like the CONSTRAINT reacts BEFORE the trigger...